# Expression Encoder SDK source codes to programmatically encode videos played on Apple devices

Tags: c#, expression-encoder, expression-encoder-sdk

I am working with VS 2010, C#, and I find the following link that has SDK source codes to programmatically encode videos to play on MS Silverlight-installed browsers:

http://www.cognifide.com/blogs/marketing-technology/microsoft-smooth-streaming-part-3/

However, the source codes from that link are used to programmically encode videos in only Silverlight output.  The output files for Silverlight come with extensions like .ism, .ismc, .ismv

I am looking for C# source codes using the same Expression Encoder SDK in VS 2010 to do the same function to programmatically encode videos played on Apple devices.  For Apple encoded files, I expect some source codes that can encode and generate files of extensions as .m3u8, .ts, .ismx, and manifest file .ism

I am using Expression Encoder 4.0

Answer (score 0):

The sample you linked is using `WindowsMediaOutputFormat()` and `WmaAudioProfile()` which isn't readable by iOS-device so try replacing those classes with [Mp4OutputFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.expression.encoder.mp4outputformat%28v=expression.30%29) and [AacAudioProfile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.expression.encoder.profiles.aacaudioprofile%28v=expression.30%29.aspx) and then see how it works.

Comment: Hi Karl, thank you for your reply. I already tried using  Mp4OutputFormat and AacAudioProfile as follows.  However, the encoded files and other files are created for Silverlight with extensions like .ism, .ismc, .ismv in output folder.

Comment: For Apple encoded files, I expect some source codes that can encode and generate files of extensions as .m3u8, .ts, .ismx, and manifest file .ism

Comment: It seems that you need the Pro-version of Expression Encoder to create mp4/h264 video so I can't test it out myself I'm afraid but since it can be done from the Expression Encoder interface (there are several samples of it if you google for it) it should work fine using code as well. Can't really help you out more though, sorry.

Comment: Karl, yes, I am using a licensed Expression Encoder Pro 4.0.  Thank you for your reply. I can use the EE 4 tool to encode video files.  However, I'd like to do that using source codes C#.